# Variable id not defined outside moongoose function NODE JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

i want to assing two diferent values to the same variable depends the result of the moongose query but im gettin this error

```
events.js:187
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

ReferenceError: barberInfo is not defined
```

this is my code in node js

```
barber.findOne({id:idBarber},function(err,response){
        if(response){
          //if barber exists in the database 
          barberInfo =response.toJSON();
        }else{
          //if no exists in the database
          barberInfo={
            id:0,
            stairs:0.0,
            numberServices:0,
            urlImg: "https://i.pinimg.com/736x/a4/93/25/a493253f2b9b3be6ef48886bbf92af58.jpg",
            name: "Sin",
            lastName : "Asignar",
            phone : "000-000-0000"
          }
        }
      });
console.log(barberInfo);
```

I defined the variable in the two cases, how can i define it ?

Comment: What exactly is the question? is it about `id` or other variable? because title and actual question differs.

Comment: mongoose call is async one . `console.log` execute before mongoose finished .You can console log  inside the call back of mongoose response .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`barberInfo` is not defined you need to defined before assigning any value.

```
barber.findOne({id:idBarber},function(err,response){
        let barberInfo;
        if(response){
          //if barber exists in the database 
          barberInfo =response.toJSON();
        }else{
          //if no exists in the database
          barberInfo={
            id:0,
            stairs:0.0,
            numberServices:0,
            urlImg: "https://i.pinimg.com/736x/a4/93/25/a493253f2b9b3be6ef48886bbf92af58.jpg",
            name: "Sin",
            lastName : "Asignar",
            phone : "000-000-0000"
          }
        }
        console.log(barberInfo);
      });
```

Answer (score 2):

In Javascript `var` are "function scoped". So, the scope of `barberInfo` is the callback function. The variable cannot be accessed outside the function.

What you are trying to do is print the value of `response`. You must do it inside the callback function. If you do it outside, it will be executed immediately, and you will not get the expected result. So, following code would give "**wrong results**".

```
let response = null; // define response variable

collection.findOne({id:searchId}, function(err, result) {
  response = result;
});

console.log(response); //this line will be executed immediately after "findOne" call. 
                       //It will not wait for the callback function execution.
```

Try writing code using promises.

```
collection.findOne({id:searchId}).then(result => {
  console.log(result);
  return result;
}).catch(err => {
  //handle error
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The barberInfo variable is not defined outside the callback function. You need to move the line: `console.log(barberInfo);` within the callback function

Answer (score 1):

`barberInfo` is not defined and you also need to add an error check in your callback. Try the following

```js
barber.findOne({id:idBarber},function(err,response){
        let barberInfo = null;
        if (err) {
          console.log(err.stack);
          return;
        }
        if(response){
          //if barber exists in the database 
          barberInfo =response.toJSON();
        }else{
          //if no exists in the database
          barberInfo={
            id:0,
            stairs:0.0,
            numberServices:0,
            urlImg: "https://i.pinimg.com/736x/a4/93/25/a493253f2b9b3be6ef48886bbf92af58.jpg",
            name: "Sin",
            lastName : "Asignar",
            phone : "000-000-0000"
          }
        }
        console.log(barberInfo);
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this code below:

```js
const myexampleFunction = async() => {
  const barberInfo = barber.findOne({id:idBarber},function(err,response){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if(response){
        //if barber exists in the database 
        resolve(response.toJSON())
      }else{
        resolve({
          id:0,
          stairs:0.0,
          numberServices:0,
          urlImg: "https://i.pinimg.com/736x/a4/93/25/a493253f2b9b3be6ef48886bbf92af58.jpg",
          name: "Sin",
          lastName : "Asignar",
          phone : "000-000-0000"
        });
      }
    })
  });
  // your barberinfo
  console.log(await barberInfo);
}
```

> From an example above, I put your code in `myexampleFunction`, so, if you have some function, you can put your code in there and dont forget to add `async` function in your function, because we're using await here.

I hope it can help you.

Comment: If my answer help you to solve your problem, then don't forget to mark as the right answer. Thanks in advance